# Why does running exported jar file give "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException; Class not found"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use Apache Spark 2.0 with Scala.

When I export the package and trying to run it from the cmd I have the problems which I think are related to the Spark Libraries.

[image]

1. How could I include that libraries in my jar file?
2. How could I run an application in that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's "Apache Spark 2.0 with Scala" you could (should?) define a `libraryDependency` in `build.sbt` and `assemble` it (using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin).

That's what I'd call a *professional* way (but that's just me).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer; it was pretty logical. I could add the missing jars with "--jars"

The code line in the CMD was something like

```
spark-submit --class com.datalabcommunity.spark.MovieSimilarities --jars C:\spark\jars\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar C:\MovieSims.jar 50
```

Hope that other person with the same problem find this answer useful